# Insert if not exit else skip

Tags: mysql

Before inserting the movie details I am trying to check if the movie details are presnt in the DB or not. If the details are already present then not to insert nor to update.I simply want to skip .

```
INSERT INTO jos_movie (movie_name, language, cast,movie_release,director,rating,rating_count,movie_ids)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'test','null','yahoo','Dec 21, 2012','himmat',250,230,'43677') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT movie_name FROM jos_movie WHERE movie_name = 'yahoo')
```

with the above query the value is getting update everytime I am running it. Its not checking. Where I am wrong in this?

Thanks I got my answer

I was inserting the test movie not yahoo !. Thats so stupid of me. Thanks

Comment: Check about unique indexes in mysql

Comment: Because you are inserting a row with `movie_name = 'test'`

Comment: PS: why do you even need a nested query `tmp`?